# Embedding a monoid into a group via its monoid ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, noncommutative-rings, group-rings, topological-rings

Suppose I have a monoid $(M,\, \cdot,\, e)$ equipped with a monoid homomorphism $\textrm{length} : M \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_+$ into the monoid of natural numbers under addition where $e$ is the only element of length $0$.

Consider the monoid ring $R := \mathbb{Z}[M]$ and the two-sided ideal $I := \{ p \in R \mid \sum_{x \in M} p(x) = 0  \}$, which is well-defined as elements of the monoid ring have finite support.

Note that the support of any element of $I$ is either empty or contains an element of length at least $1$.
Therefore, the support of any element of $I^2$ is either empty or contains an element of length at least $2$.
And it follows by induction that $\bigcap_{n > 0} I^n = \{ 0 \}\ (\star)$ as no element with finite support can contain an element of length longer than every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now let $\hat{R}$ be the $I$-adic completion of $R$ defined in the usual way as the ring of Cauchy sequences quotiented by those that converge to $0$.
As a result of $(\star)$, we can embed any element of $R$ into $\hat{R}$ as a constant sequence and, therefore, any element of $M$ into the multiplicative monoid of $\hat{R}$.

Furthermore, each element of the form $1 - i \in R$ with $i \in I$ has an inverse in $\hat{R}$:
$$
(1 - i) \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} i^n = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} i^n - i\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} i^n = 1 + i\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} i^n - i\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} i^n = 1
$$
where the sum is well-defined as its sequence of partial sums is evidently Cauchy.

However, for any $x \in M$, we can write $x = 1 - (1 - x) \in R$ with $1 - x \in I$.
It seems to follow, therefore, that we have constructed an embedding of $M$ into the group of units of $\hat{R}$.

Now obviously this cannot be the case as not all such monoids can be embedded in a group but
I can't find where the argument breaks down. There should be some issue even if we make the further assumption that the monoid is cancellative or indeed orderable as Mal'cev constructed such a monoid that cannot be embedded into a group.

**Update:**

- It is not true that $\bigcap_{n > 0} I^n = \{ 0 \}$ when $M$ is not cancellative.
  For example, if $M = \langle a,\, b,\, c \mid ac = bc \rangle$ then we have that $(b - a)(1 - c) = b - a - bc + ac = b - a \in I$.
- However, it still cannot hold if we assume $M$ is cancellative because of Mal'cev's counterexample.

Comment: It may be a problem that the existence of a length function with the properties you want is rare and most monoids do not possess such a thing.

Comment: @PeterKropholler indeed, one may compare it to the group case, where (appropriately defined) any group admitting a length function is free (see Lyndon-Schupp). But I suppose that depends on how “length function” is defined. A priori it seems any such monoid is at least cancellative.

Comment: Why does the support of every nonzero element of $I$ contain an element of lenght at least $1$? Do you assume that the only element of lenght zero is the identity? I think that you should be clearer about what you mean by "lenght homomorphism".

Comment: The monoid <{a, b, c} | ab = ac> cannot be embedded in a group precise because it isn't cancellative and yet has a length function. The case for a group will be different because we'd need the length to be over the integers but then we can consider the sub-monoid of positive elements and replicate the argument. And indeed the integers are a non-free example of such a group.

Comment: @AntoineLabelle yes the length of zero has to be the identity. By a length homomorphism I just meant a monoid homomorphism. I'll clarify that now.

Comment: @EddieJones Ah yes I was thinking strangely with cancellativity. Why are the integers a non-free example? Looks quite free to me :-)

Comment: You're right sorry they are a free group but say if we take the free Abelian group on two generators then it is not free but has a length function. Or if this still counts as free then we can add a third generator that doesn't commute with the other two and still have a length function.

Comment: @EddieJones But the problem still remains -- every monoid admits a homomorphism into the natural numbers under addition, just map everything to $0$. You are assuming more than you are stating.

Comment: Yes you're right I have made the assumption that only the identity has length 0 (which I'll add now) but that doesn't get in the way of the rest of the proof and we still have counterexamples.

Comment: @EddieJones Why is the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_n (1-a)^n$ Cauchy in your examples $\langle a, b, c | ab=ac\rangle$?

Comment: A sequence ${(p_n)}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy for the $I$-adic topology if, for every $d \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p_n - p_m \in I^d$ for all $n \geq m > N$. In this case, we have that: $\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} (1 - a)^k - \sum_{0 \leq k \leq m} (1 - a)^k = \sum_{m < k \leq n} (1 - a)^k$ which is in $I^m$ as $I^2 \subseteq I$ and $I$ is an additive sub-group of $R$ because it is an ideal. Therefore, we can just pick $N$ to $d$.

Comment: What does $\sum_{x\in M}p(x)$ mean when $p\in R$?

Comment: $R$ is defined as the subset of functions $M \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with finitely many non-zero values. We can think of it as elements of a polynomial with integer coefficients and elements of $M$ instead of variables and where $p(x)$ is the coefficient associated with $x$. So $\sum_{x \in M} p(x)$ is the sum of the coefficients.

Comment: Malcev's example has a length function of the sort you want.  All relations are length 2. The mistake is still the same.  The elements of the same length may sum to 0 due to the relations and so I^n may have elements with homogenous components much smaller degrees

Comment: Thanks for your response @BenjaminSteinberg. Can you provide an example from Mal'cev's monoid? I am now wondering if it holds given Malcev's condition or equivalently if it is known that $M$ can be embedded in a group.

Comment: Malcev doesn't have a single condition.  He has infinitely many.  Any I find them too complicated to work with in practice

Comment: I don't have time to play with this now.  Malcev's monoid has generators $x,y,u,v,a,b,c,d$ and relations $xa=yb$, $xc=yd$ and $ua=vb$.  His observation is that in any group these relations imply $uc=vd$.  Presumably you can show that $uc-vd$ is in the intersection.

Comment: Notice if you have a monoid $M$ with a length function such that $\bigcap_{n\geq 1} I^n=0$, then $M$ must be residually finite (and even residually a finite $p$-group for all $p$) and I seriously doubt all group embeddable cancellative monoids with a length function are residually finite $p$groups.  The point is if you factor out $I^n$ and go modulo $p^k$, you get something finite and the group $1+I$ goes to finite $p$-group.

Comment: How do you deduce that it has to be residually finite from this intersection property? Is there some relationship between the powers of $I$ and the congruences of $M$?

Comment: I'm assuming that $M$ is finitely generated.  The quotient $ZM\to Z_pM/I^n$  restricts to a homomorphism $M\to Z_pM/I^n$ and $Z_{p}M/I^n$ is finite since there are only finitely many elements of each length if $M$ is finitely generated.  If $m, m'$ map to the same element under all these maps, then $m-m'$ belongs to $I^n$ for all $n$.  Otherwise $m-m'$ is nonzero in $ZM/I^n$ for some $n$.  Clearly then $p(m-m')\notin I^n$ (one should check but it seems ok) for a prime $p$ and so you can separate $m-m'$ in $Z_pM/I^n$.